# Most performant way to parse strange JSON containing arrays of mixed types?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm reading data via a websocket, and the data comes back as valid JSON but is strangely formatted.

Here is an example of the data that comes back:

```
[1002,null,[98,"0.00011972","0.00012097","0.00011972","-0.16635331","38.03938952","305130.84018577",0,"0.00014363","0.00011168"]]
```

How would I turn this into a well-formed class in C# using Json.NET?

My ideal class would look something like this:

```
class Message
{
    int MessageId { get; set; }
    int? MessageVal { get; set; }
    Payload Payload { get; set; }
}
class Payload
{
    int PayloadId { get; set; }
    string Item1 { get; set; }
    string Item2 { get; set; }
    ...
    string Item8 { get; set; }
}
```

How can this be done?  Hardmode: efficient and fast

Thanks!

Comment: Parse it to a `List<object>`? What are you actually trying to get out of it? It's an array that contains, in one place, another array. And do you really want to treat those values as strings?

Comment: Just to confirm - you don't know the size of the array. I guess if you did, you would have just used the class you posted?

Comment: That json array is valid and also extremely painful to manage. Why use arrays when objects exists? Where does that come from?

Comment: I have no control over the format of the data, that is how it is being sent.  @Livanov - it would never serialize into the class I posted.  Note that there is no key/value pattern in the sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no control over the shape of the data coming back to you then you can use the following:

Class definitions:

```
public class Message
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public int? MessageVal { get; set; }
    public Payload Payload { get; set; }
}

public class Payload
{
    public int PayloadId { get; set; }
    public string[] Items { get; set;}
}
```

Deserialization:

```
var json = @"[1002,null,[98,""0.00011972"",""0.00012097"",""0.00011972"",""-0.16635331"",""38.03938952"",""305130.84018577"",0,""0.00014363"",""0.00011168""]]";

var data = JArray.Parse(json);

var message = new Message()
{
    MessageId = data[0].ToObject<int>(),
    MessageVal = data[1].ToObject<int?>(),
    Payload = new Payload()
    {
        PayloadId = data[2][0].ToObject<int>(),
        Items = data[2].Skip(1).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()
    }
};
```

Comment: Will this approach be any better or worse vs. using dynamic?  These messages will be coming in with very high frequency, so preferably the parsing will be very efficient in regards to CPU usage.

Comment: @Arash [The only way to find out for sure which is faster is to test it yourself in your environment.](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @Arash You mean is this faster than deserializing to a dynamic object? I don't know for sure but I would think so. I've never had a need to use dynamic objects so I have never really looked into them. I know there is a lot of stuff going on under the hood when it comes to dynamic objects. I would think that extra stuff would impact performance.

Comment: Thanks @JasonBoyd, marking it as answer as it is a clean enough approach and looks similar to the javascript code that parses this same data.  Regards!